# Using Zend Form and Dojo without using ZF MVC

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, zend-form

for our applications we use Zend_form, without any part of the ZF MVC stack. We would like to make dynamics forms (Javascript, Ajax powered), we are looking Dojo, but it does not working "out of the box". Online Zend Framework documentation did not help, because all examples talk about Zend_Form on MVC applications.

Where is our error? What are we missing? Here is the code :

```
$oViewZF = new Zend_View();
Zend_Dojo::enableView($oViewZF);
$oViewZF->addHelperPath(PATH_ZF . '1.11.4/library/Zend/Dojo/View/Helper', 'Zend_Dojo_View_Helper');
$oViewZF->dojo()->setCdnVersion('1.1.1');
$oViewZF->dojo()->setLocalPath('dojo/dojo/dojo.js')->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');

$form = new Zend_Dojo_Form();
$form->setAction($url)->setMethod('post')->setTranslator(self::ZendFormTranslate());
$form->addPrefixPath('Zend_Dojo_Form', 'Zend/Dojo/Form/')
       ->addElementPrefixPath('Zend_Dojo_Form', 'Zend/Dojo/Form/')
       ->addDisplayGroupPrefixPath('Zend_Dojo_Form', 'Zend/Dojo/Form/');
$form->setDecorators(array('FormElements', array('TabContainer', array('id' => 'tabContainer', 'style' =>
'width: 600px; height: 500px;', 'dijitParams' => array('tabPosition' => 'top'))), 'DijitForm'));

echo $oViewZF->headScript(); #show nothing
echo $oViewZF->dojo(); #print "style @import dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"; and <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
echo $oViewZF->layout()->content; #show nothing
echo $oViewZF->inlineScript(); #show nothing

$birthday = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_DateTextBox('birthday');
$birthday->setLabel('Birthday');
$form->addElement($birthday);
$form->addElement('submit', 'cmd', array('label' => 'Créer'));
echo $form->render($oViewZF);
```

It show only a text imput field without any JS error :

```
<dt id="birthday-label"><label for="birthday" class="optional">Birthday</label></dt>
<dd><input id="birthday" name="birthday" value="" type="text"></dd>
```

We would like to use date pickers, fields only required/visibles when a checkbox is checked, and so on.

Regards,
Cédric

ps: if I place the $oViewZF->Dojo() (see [Zend_Dojo_Form in a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829609/zend-dojo-form-in-a-layout)) after the render() call, I have this JS error

> Erreur : uncaught exception: [Exception... "String contains an invalid character"  code: "5" nsresult: "0x80530005  (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR)" location: "http://127.0.0.1/~cedric/EC/VOOELFE/code/decideur/public/dojo/dojo/_base/_loader/bootstrap.js Line: 1930"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer :

```
$oViewZF = new Zend_View();

Zend_Dojo::enableView($oViewZF);
$oViewZF->addHelperPath(CHEMIN_ZF . '1.11.4/library/Zend/Dojo/View/Helper', 'Zend_Dojo_View_Helper');
$oViewZF->dojo()->setLocalPath('dojo/dojo/dojo.js')->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');

$form->addPrefixPath('Zend_Dojo_Form', 'Zend/Dojo/Form/') 
    ->addElementPrefixPath('Zend_Dojo_Form', 'Zend/Dojo/Form/') 
    ->addDisplayGroupPrefixPath('Zend_Dojo_Form', 'Zend/Dojo/Form/');

echo $form->render($oViewZF);
echo $oViewZF->dojo();
echo $oViewZF->inlineScript();
```

The dojo() call must be after the render() call, and one of my fields was badly declared and created the JS error.